# Unexpected behaviour by inspect function in R

Tags: r, apriori

Working on apriory algorithms and trying to convert rules object to dataframe as below. it works well and data has been stored in datafarme

```
ruledf=inspect(sort(rules, by = 'lift')[1:100])
```

But when I changed code to store more observation (1000) in dataframe,then it failed.

```
ruledf=inspect(sort(rules, by = 'lift')[1:1000])
summary(ruledf)
Length  Class   Mode 
 0   NULL   NULL
```

I will really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

the `inspect` method is only for displaying rules. It does not return any information (see `? inspect`). You most likely want to do this

```
as(rules, "data.frame")
```

or

```
DATAFRAME(rules)
```